# How to impl a generic trait with narrower "type"s in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

Coming from the .NET world, I have been trying to apply dependency injection to my Actix-Web application, by extracting `interface`s. Intuitively in my opinion, `interface`s are `trait`s in Rust, however, without any success.

Necessary imports:

```rust
use async_trait::async_trait;
use sqlx::{postgres::PgRow, FromRow, PgPool, Row};

use blahblah::MyError;
```

Here is the `trait`:

```rust
#[async_trait]
pub trait DBClient<'a, T, R>
where
    R: Row,
    T: FromRow<'a, R>,
{
    async fn insert_one(&self, pool: &PgPool, query_raw: &str) -> Result<T, MyError>;
}
```

Here is the `impl`:

```rust
pub struct DBClientMain;

#[async_trait]
impl<'a, T, R> DBClient<'a, T, R> for DBClientMain
where
    R: Row,
    T: FromRow<'a, R>,
{
    async fn insert_one(&self, pool: &PgPool, query_raw: &str) -> Result<T, MyError> {
        let res: T = sqlx::query(query_raw)
            .fetch_one(pool)
            .await
            .map(|r: PgRow| {
                // error: mismatched types expected reference `&R` found reference `&PgRow`
                T::from_row(&r).unwrap()
            })
            .map_err(|err| {
                // to save for brevity
            })?;
        Ok(res)
    }
}
```

The reason why `R: Row`, as the trait bound, is required here(trait `DBClient`), it is because `Row` is required in the trait `FromRow<'r, Row>`. I do not know how to "narrow" it.

What's more, `PgRow` is a struct, not a trait, which I cannot apply it as the trait bound either.

```rust
pub trait FromRow<'r, R: Row>: Sized {
    fn from_row(row: &'r R) -> Result<Self, Error>;
}
```

The `PgRow` implements `Row` by default:

```rust
impl Row for PgRow {
    type Database = Postgres;

    fn columns(&self) -> &[PgColumn] {
        &self.metadata.columns
    }

    fn try_get_raw<I>(&self, index: I) -> Result<PgValueRef<'_>, Error>
    where
        I: ColumnIndex<Self>,
    {
        let index = index.index(self)?;
        let column = &self.metadata.columns[index];
        let value = self.data.get(index);

        Ok(PgValueRef {
            format: self.format,
            row: Some(&self.data.storage),
            type_info: column.type_info.clone(),
            value,
        })
    }
}
```

Sorry ahead for my mixing `interface`, let's say in C#, and `trait` in Rust. I cannot find more proper words.

It looks like that I was trying to "upcast" `PgRow` to `Row`, given that `PgRow` implemented `Row`. However, (such) inheritance is not supported in Rust. Am I on the right track?

More importantly:

How to resolve the error? (Solved for now)

How to `impl` a generic `trait` with narrower "type"s? (Given the difference between `interface` and `trait`, is this a valid question in Rust?)

Relevant, and open to discussion:

Is there any way to apply effective constraints on `query_raw: &str` as the function parameter, such as type checking, etc.?

Is such abstract recommended in the Rust world?

Comment: Why do you express your row type as a generic `R` when you always pass a `PgPool` and therefore it would always be a `PgRow`?

Comment: @kmdreko, thanks for your quick reply.  The reason added in the question body :).

Comment: I was asking why you need `R` in your trait at all. If it's always using a `PgPool`, wouldn't just  `T: FromRow<'a, PgRow>` be better?

Comment: @kmdreko, OMG, you saved my day! Thanks! This works, and this works for now. I have no near plan to generalize it more than solving the current problem. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

This actually works:

```
#[async_trait]
pub trait DBClient<'a, T>
where
    T: FromRow<'a, PgRow>,
{
    async fn insert_one(&self, pool: &PgPool, query_raw: &str) -> Result<T, MyError>;
}

pub struct DBClientMain;

#[async_trait]
impl<'a, T> DBClient<'a, T> for DBClientMain
where
    T: FromRow<'a, PgRow>,
{
    async fn insert_one(&self, pool: &PgPool, query_raw: &str) -> Result<T, MyError> {
        let res: T = sqlx::query(query_raw)
            .fetch_one(pool)
            .await
            .map(|r: PgRow| {
                T::from_row(&r).unwrap()
            })
            .map_err(|err| {
              // to save for brevity
            })?;
        Ok(res)
    }
}
```

Great thanks @kmdreko. You saved my day!

I have no near plan to generalize it more than solving the current problem, but I will generalize the trait to higher degrees, such as on `Row`, `PgPool`, etc.

I still do not have clear distinctions between `interface` vs `trait`, such as upcasting, etc. Hopefully I can master them soon.